# Android Drawerlayout touchlistener not working

Tags: android, drawerlayout

I'm using android drawerlayout but any touchlisteners (including button onclicks) in left drawer isn't working.
Every time I try to touch left drawer, **it closes right away.**

My source code in MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ...

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(myDrawerListener);
    mDrawerView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("myTag", "hello world");
            return true;
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.drawer_my_btn).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("myTag", "my");
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.drawer_shared_btn).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("myTag", "shared");
        }
    });

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    createMemo(savedInstanceState);
}
```

and activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:text="Company: "/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/drawer_company_code"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center|left"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:text="ID: "/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/drawer_user_id"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center|left"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/drawer_my_btn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="My Notes"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/drawer_shared_btn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="Shared Notes"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshLayout 
        android:id="@+id/ptr_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <adapter.StaggeredGridView
            android:id="@+id/grid_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:item_margin="8dp"
            app:column_count="@integer/grid_column_count"
            android:background="@drawable/bg"/>
    </uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The logs you see in the onCreate is not called when I try to touch left_drawer or buttons in it.

I've tried clickable="true" to left_drawer, but it doesn't work.
Is it focus problem? or touchevent problem?
Please help me!

Comment: The Drawer contents need to be listed second in the layout. The main content should be listed first for correct z-ordering.

Comment: Thank you Mike! It's solved!!! YEAH~~~

Comment: @MikeM.,please post your comment as ans so it may help other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By reordering layouts in xml, it's solved!
I had to put pulltorefreshlayout first and then put left_drawer(linearlayout).

Thank you Mike!